# No Database Provider Error even when DBContext is configured

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Mine is a .net core  web api project with EF. My plan was to use connection string from Appsettings.json and thus I configured like this in startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<dbLNePMODev1Context>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
```

Also here is how my DBContext constructor looks like

```
public partial class dbLNePMODev1Context : DbContext
{
    public dbLNePMODev1Context()
    {
    }

    public dbLNePMODev1Context(DbContextOptions<dbLNePMODev1Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
....
.....
}
```

But even then I am getting the following error when trying to connect with DB

> 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
> provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
> method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
> If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

Sorry I believe I could be missing something since I am new to EF. Please help me what I did wrong here.

Comment: Where did the error occur? Post the code that threw and the *full* exception, including the stack trace, not just the message. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Exception Details` in the exception popout in Visual Studio. The full text contains the exact location where the error occurred and the chain of calls that led to it. Perhaps you created the DbContext directly instead of using the DI?

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. You are absolutely right, On that function we were using direct reference to the DBcontext instead of DI

Comment: *Remove* the default constructor altogether. This way you won't run into this problem again. The default constructor should be used *only* if you intend to configure the DbContext through its `OnConfiguring` method entirely. When you do that though, you lose the ability to change connection strings, unit test and generally pass options at runtime